# how to convert a full function string to a javascript function without using eval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a varible string like

```
var z = "anuj.working = false;anuj.downloadFile(event,'opp-for-download','anuj@anuj Demo Guide For Partners.pdf.zip (5.3 MB)','/file/dam/mail Anuj@anuj @Anuj  Demo Guide For Partners.pdf.zip','zip',null)";
```

how can i convert it to a function. i don't want to use eval().

Comment: Remove the quotes. Hahahahaaha just kidding. Couldn't resist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the variable string as a new function, then call that function:

```
var func = new Function(theFunctionString);
func();
```

I think this offers what you're looking for, but without having `anuj.` defined, I couldn't run a successful test.

Comment: Awesome Zac Thanks aton.

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate in such a way as it from a JSON object, you can use JSON.parse to convert it to an object that will allow you to call it as a method of the object.